# Is there a way of only printing the dictionary in a Counter() output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am counting the total occurrences of each item:

```
from collections import Counter

colors = ['green', 'blue', 'green', 'white', 'white']
colorTotals = Counter(colours)

print(colorTotals)
```

Running the code prints: `Counter({'green': 2, 'white': 2, 'blue': 1})` but I only want to print the dictionary, something like: `{'green': 2, 'white': 2, 'blue': 1}`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `print(dict(colourTotals))`

Answer (score 2):

```
print(dict(colorTotals))
```

Which outputs

```
{'green': 2, 'blue': 1, 'white': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

`dict(colorTotals)` is the standard way. If you're golfing, you could also use `{**colorTotals}` or `{}|colorTotals` or `colorTotals|{}` (the latter two require Python 3.9). I see no circumstance where you'd ever use your `str`+`literal_eval` way.